# Unable to boot Windows 7 "error while reading boot configuration data" and inability to restore

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, uefi, windows-8-upgrade, bcd

I have tried to install Windows 8 Pro over Windows 7 Ultimate, but the installation failed to install the new OS and even to restore the old one.

I get the following error:

```
File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
Description: an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data
```

### System setup

- Laptop is an ASUS N76VZ
- HDD0 (1TB): openSUSE 12.3 in EFI boot mode
- HDD1 (1TB): Windows 7 in EFI boot mode
- BitLocker suspended on `C:\` before trying to install Win8
- Other partitions are TrueCrypt protected

Data is *almost* back up. I won't lose much by formatting, apart from hours of software reinstallation

### Steps to create the problem

As I said, I tried to install Windows 8 pro upgrading the existing Windows 7 Ultimate. I started setup from Windows, suspended BitLocker as requested, uninstalled a few Intel USB 3.0 drivers that are not compatible with Windows 8 and let setup go.

When rebooted, it first started with the new Windows logo, then rebooted, as expected, an then the Windows Boot Manager screen appeared. Three menu options available:

- Windows 8
- Windows installation
- Windows 7

I tried to boot 8 for the first time, but it rebooted shortly after. Then I chose Windows installation and that time the Windows installer told me there was an error during the installation. OK, no problem, I can try again...

But now I can't boot Windows 7 anymore.

### What I have tried

I found [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-bootmgr-is-missing-resolved-using-winre/8bb148bc-8035-4847-9696-888f7a0a9720)

I tried to boot from Win7 DVD (using UEFI) and use automatic system restore option. These failed (method 1 of linked article). I tried to open console and use `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. It detected D:\Windows as installation directory but the (translated into English) error is the following when I press [Y]es

```
Unable to identitfy the requested system device. More devices correspond to the identification criteria without distinction.
```

I *guess* that this refers to the Linux installation.

I would like to ask how to repair EFI boot partition for Windows 7 given that BitLocker is *suspended*

### The question

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self fixed. Here is how.

### The short answer

Physically disconnect any other disk rather than Windows's boot drive, launch Recovery mode from DVD (booting with UEFI) and let Windows repair itelf

#### The explanation

Basically Windows Boot Repair doesn't like other UEFI-based OSes installed. I'll update the answer if disconnecting first hard drive helps me install Windows 8